# How should I evaluate equivalency of floating point numpy matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, bitwise-and

While working on a matrix equivalency problem, which involves a variety of inverse transformations, I found some unexpected behaviour I wanted to clarify. I've made all the matrices equivalent here, as the actual transformations aren't really relevant to the issue I'm having.

```
a = np.matrix([ 1, 1], [-1, 4]])

x = inv(a)
y = inv(a)
z = inv(a)

(x == y & z).all()

Note: x = matrix([ 0.8, -0.2],
                 [ 0.2,  0.2]])
```

Which returns the following error message:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the 
inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the 
casting rule ''safe''
```

Is this error is being raised because `&` operators can't be used with floating points? The following methods seem to return correct answers, but I would appreciate input on a preferred method for the given problem.

```
(np.equal(x, y) & np.equal(y, z)).all()
True

np.equal([x,y,z], [y,z,x]).all()
True
```

Comment: Look into `np.isclose`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` does [bitwise and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)). It seems you want to check whether the matrices are identical -- i.e. check whether both `x == y` and `x == z`, in which case you need [logical and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html), e.g. like this:

```
np.logical_and(x==y, x==z).all()
```

Or, as suggest in the comment, you could use [`np.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
np.logical_and(np.isclose(x, y), np.isclose(x, z)).all()
```

The reasons why your two suggestions work are:

- The first one works because False/True are understood as 0/1, so the bitwise operation in this case happens to be equal to the logical operation.
- Your second suggestion constructs a 3D matrix from the three 2D matrices and checks for equality as in checking `x == y`, `y == z`, and `z == x`, but one of these is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html) for `bitwise_and`:

"Only integer and boolean types are handled."

I suspect that is the source of your `TypeError`.

For checking the equivalency of floating point matrices, I have in the past defined an acceptable margin of error and checked that every pair of elements between two matrices is within that margin.